# How to use a PHP class from another file?

Tags: php

Let's say I've got two files **class.php** and **page.php**

**class.php**

```
<?php 
    class IUarts {
        function __construct() {
            $this->data = get_data('mydata');
        }
    }
?>
```

That's a very rudamentary example, but let's say  I want to use:

```
$vars = new IUarts(); 
print($vars->data);
```

in my page.php file; how do I go about doing that? If I do `include(LIB.'/class.php');` it yells at me and gives me `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class IUarts in /dir/class.php on line 4`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include_once.php) or [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)/[`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require_once.php)

```
require_once('class.php');
```

---

Alternatively, use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)
by adding to `page.php`

```
<?php 
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

$vars = new IUarts(); 
print($vars->data);    
?>
```

It also works adding that `__autoload` function in a lib that you include on every file like `utils.php`.

There is also this post that has a nice and different approach.

[Efficient PHP auto-loading and naming strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791899/efficient-php-auto-loading-and-naming-strategies)

Comment: "__autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead" Since this result is fairly high on google, maybe someone should edit it and point this out more clearly?

Comment: This accepted answer is not straight to the point about the question and the error message shown (as a result of multiple inclusion of the same class). Not downvoting as it is nevertheless useful and correct.

Answer (score 12):

In this case, it appears that you've already included the file somewhere. But for class files, you should really "include" them using `require_once` to avoid that sort of thing; it won't include the file if it already has been. (And you should usually use `require[_once]`, not `include[_once]`, the difference being that `require` will cause a fatal error if the file doesn't exist, instead of just issuing a warning.)

Answer (score 9):

Use `include_once` instead.
This error means that you have already included this file.

`include_once(LIB.'/class.php');`

Answer (score 3):

Use `include("class.classname.php");`

And class should use `<?php //code  ?> not <? //code  ?>`

Comment: That second thing you said isn't specific to this question or correct. `<?  ?>` is just newer syntax, I believe it can be enabled or disable in the `php.ini`.  (Sorry to resurrect this)

Comment: I think what he was saying is that shorthand version isnt always enabled on all servers and occasionally you may be using a webhosting environment where you can't modify the php.ini, so it is safer and more compatible if you use <?php instead of the shorthand <? version.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/_path/_of/_filename.php');
```

This will also help in importing files in from different folders.
Try `extends` method to inherit the classes in that file and reuse the functions